# How to write into R14(link register) in ARMv7

Tags: arm, cpu-registers, cortex-m

I am trying to load 0xFFFFFFF9 to LR register at the end of an interrupt so that it can exit the interrupt. I am doing this as my code tampers with the LR register in the interrupt code. Simple MOV instruction seems not to work.
Any suggestions on how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a code snippet of the troubles code?

Comment: I hope you mean armv7-m rather than arm7?  that is not how you return from an interrupt in a cortex-m most definitely not an ARM7.  If you read the documentation from ARM you can if this is an armv7-m do this in one instruction (what is ~0xFFFFFFF9 equal to?) or the traditional thumb armv6-m (armv4t(arm7)) would be to probably move immediate to a lower register, negate, mov to the high register.

Comment: all of this is in the arm documentation that you should have before venturing into assembly language.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating LR is common in situations like this.  Although the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48992389/605307) is correct that it's the PC that's sensitive to the special values, it's common (and consistent with recommended practice) to use `BX LR` as a return instruction so manipulation of LR prior to the return is appropriate.

There's no reason why a MOV shouldn't work if the constant is within the permitted range; and if it isn't, use the `LDR =` pseudo-instruction (on the stock ARM assembler anyway, don't know about other assemblers) to avoid the grunt-work of putting the constant together by hand.

If the MOV appears not to be working (you haven't provided any code, or said what you mean by 'seems not to work') then check that LR isn't being overwritten just before the return.  Remember that the 'implicit return' is a very common pattern, where LR is pushed to the stack at the top of the function and popped direct into PC at the end:

```
PUSH {r4-r6,lr}
...
POP {r4-r6,pc} ; implicit return
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be necessary to use the LR, it is the PC which is sensitive to the special value.

From the Cortex-M generic device [user guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Babefdjc.html)

> Exception return occurs when the processor is in Handler mode and
>   executes one of the following instructions attempts to set the PC to
>   an EXC_RETURN value:
>
> - an LDM or POP instruction that loads the PC
> - an LDR instruction with PC as the destination
> - a BX instruction using any register.
>
> The processor saves an EXC_RETURN value to the LR on exception entry.
>   The exception mechanism relies on this value to detect when the
>   processor has completed an exception handler. Bits[31:4] of an
>   EXC_RETURN value are 0xFFFFFFF. When the processor loads a value
>   matching this pattern to the PC it detects that the operation is a not
>   a normal branch operation and, instead, that the exception is
>   complete. Therefore, it starts the exception return sequence.
>   Bits[3:0] of the EXC_RETURN value indicate the required return stack
>   and processor mode, as Table 2.17 shows.

Later in the same [document](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABHGAJI.html):

> **Restrictions** You can use SP and PC only in the MOV instruction, with the following restrictions:
>
> - the second operand must be a register without shift
> - you must not specify the S suffix.
>
> When Rd is PC in a MOV instruction:
>
> - bit[0] of the value written to the PC is ignored
> - a branch occurs to the address created by forcing bit[0] of that value to 0.
>
> **Note** Though it is possible to use MOV as a branch instruction, ARM strongly recommends the use of a BX or BLX instruction to branch for
>   software portability to the ARM instruction set.